# Ag-grid external filter with column filters

Tags: reactjs, external, ag-grid-react, columnsorting

I am using external filter and column filters in ag-grid react. Both are working fine individually. And also when I filtered from columns first, and after I filter from external filter, it works. But the otherside is not working. First I want to filter table from external filter, and then from that filtered data only I wamt to filter from column filter. How can I achieve that?

Comment: did you found any solution for your question ??

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old post but this could be helpful for future readers.

The documentation doesn't cover multiple but it gives you enough to work with, or it did for me to get to a solution. https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-external/

The key is the doesExternalFilterPass function.

I essentially replaced the ageType variable with my own filtered variable which is an object.

```
filtered = {country:russia,year:2008}
```

I pass the externalFilterChanged the filtered variable

```
externalFilterChanged(filtered)
```

Then the doesExternalFilterPass(node) i have changed to check both columns for my values.

```
doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
    if(filtered.country && filtered.year){
        if (node.data) {
            return node.data.country == filtered.country && node.data.year == filtered.year;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code will show all rows with russia and 2008